# C# Namespace, Imported Class and Editing

Tags: c#, class, namespaces, edit

I have a project that logically requires two parts. A Z80 disassembler and a TS2068 Hardware Emulation. Yes I know it's been done, but I am using this as a learning experience.

So, I have two solution folders, one for the Z80 and one for the TS2068.

Is there a way to include the TS2068 solution without having the IDE (VS2017) copy the files over, allowing me to edit the TS2068 files in its own solution.

That is, is there a way to do this so I am only working one copy of the TS2068 file set?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Z80
{
    public partial class Z80 : Form
    {
        public Z80()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initOPS();
            initCB();
            initDD();
            initED();
            initFD();
            initddcb();
            initfdcb();
        }

        TS2068.TS2068 hw = new TS2068.TS2068();
```

This is using imported code

Comment: You could have them as 2 projects within the same solution rather than 2 separate solutions.

Comment: Yeah, it is possible, you can reference one project from the other project. So you would have one solution with two projects. You can reference one project from the other, which means you only need to make code changes in one place. Try looking at this example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/project-reference-vs-dll-reference-in-visual-studio/

Comment: You could also compile one project down to a .DLL, add it to the other and reference it that way.

Comment: Basically I am already using one of the methods in inspite's referenced article.

If I did it "right" it still made a copy locally, leaving the original untouched by edits in the host solution..

Using a DLL means I'd have to continuously recompile as I am developing.

So, I will stick with my current solution and use Beyond Compare to update the dependency solution as I am developing in the host solution.